# Automatically assigning colours in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot multiple lines and automatically assign colours to the plotted lines using ggplot.  I have the following example code:

```
library(ggplot2)

A <- data.frame(x=0:10,y=0:10)
B <- data.frame(x=(seq(from=0, to=10, by=1)), y=(seq(from=0, to=5, by=0.5)))
C <- data.frame(x=(seq(from=0, to=5, by=0.5)), y=(seq(from=0, to=10, by=1)))

ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=A, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_line(data=B, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_line(data=C, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  coord_equal()
```

I know I can set this manually with:

```
geom_line(data=A, aes(x=x, y=y, col="red"))+
```

etc but is there some way I can just assign colours automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put all data frames in one and then add some column that have identifier for each line.

```
new.df<-rbind(A,B,C)
new.df$ID<-rep(c("A","B","C"),c(nrow(A),nrow(B),nrow(C)))
```

Then use this new column to set color.

```
ggplot(new.df,aes(x,y,color=ID))+geom_line()
```

[image]